# Firestore query having problem with getting the data I need on react native

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, react-redux

```
await firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection("patients")
      .doc(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
      .collection("appointment")
      .orderBy("dateTime", "asc")
      .get()
      .then((result) => {
        let appointment = result.docs.map((doc) => {
          const data = doc.data();
          const id = doc.id;
          const currentDate = moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD");
          const dt=new moment(doc.data().dateTime,'YYYY-MM-DD').format('YYYY-MM-DD');
          if(dt===currentDate){
            return { id, ...data };
          }
        });
        dispatch({ type: GET_APPOINTMENT, appointment });
      });
```

I am trying to do 3 things at once:

- Get all the appointments for today in an object
- Get all appointments after today in an object
- When an appointment passes the current time, I want to delete it from the database

How can it be done?

Comment: What type is `dateTime` in your database? Is it a Firestore Timestamp, a Javascript Date or is it in milliseconds since 01/01/1970 ?

Comment: I send it as a string like this '2021-02-27-04:30' and when return i change it to moment object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is get all the documents in the user collection in a single query, then go through each document and sort it based on whether it is in  the past, today, or in the future.

Here is an example of this, with comments explaining what's going on.

```
const db = firebase.firestore();

db
  .collection("patients")
  .doc(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
  .collection("appointment")
  .orderBy("dateTime", "asc")
  .get()
  .then(async (result) => {
    const pastAppointmentRefs = [], todayAppointments = [], futureAppointments = [];

    // Get current date in YYYY-MM-DD and milliseconds, just the once
    const currentDate = moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD");
    const currentDateMs = Date.now();
    
    result.forEach((doc) => {
      // Get appointment datetime and it's equivalent in milliseconds
      const dateTime = doc.get("dateTime"); // format: YYYY-MM-DD-HH:mm
      const dateTimeMs = moment(dateTime, 'YYYY-MM-DD-HH:mm').valueOf();
    
      // sort appointment based on dateTime
      if (dateTimeMs < currentDateMs) {
        // is in the past, could also be currently taking place
        pastAppointmentRefs.push(doc.ref);
      } else if (currentDate === dateTime.slice(0,10)) {
        // is today
        todayAppointments.push({ id: doc.id, ...doc.data() });
      } else {
        // is in the future
        futureAppointments.push({ id: doc.id, ...doc.data() });
      }}
    });

    // if there are any found appointments in the past, delete them all
    if (pastAppointmentRefs.length > 0) {
      const batch = db.batch();
      // warning! you can only delete up to 500 docs in a single batch
      pastAppointmentRefs.forEach((ref) => {
        batch.delete(ref);
      });
      await batch.commit(); // commit the changes (the deletions)
    }

    // fire the event
    dispatch({
      type: GET_APPOINTMENTS,
      today: todayAppointments,
      future: futureAppointments
    });
  });
```

Comment: the deleting function did not work unfortunately error is [Unhandled promise rejection: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: db]

Comment: @OsamaTab As this answer is written, the code functions as expected. If you didn't declare `const db = firebase.firestore()` at the top of this answer like I have, you need to change `const batch = db.batch()` to `const batch = firebase.firestore().batch()`.

Comment: sorry did not see db been declared I fixed it now thank you for the help